# OctoberCMS problem with media after changing URL

Tags: php, octobercms

I am running a OctoberCMS website.
During development, I accessed the website at `http://oldurl.de/octoberCMS`.

for this I have adjusted the path in my `cms.php`

```
'storage' => [

    'uploads' => [
        'disk'            => 'local',
        'folder'          => 'uploads',
        'path'            => '/octoberCMS/storage/app/uploads',
        'temporaryUrlTTL' => 3600,
    ],

    'media' => [
        'disk'   => 'local',
        'folder' => 'media',
        'path'   => '/octoberCMS/storage/app/media',
    ],

],
```

Everything worked wonderfully. I have now adjusted my correct URL and path accordingly, so that I now reach the CMS at `https://newurl.de`.

```
'storage' => [

    'uploads' => [
        'disk'            => 'local',
        'folder'          => 'uploads',
        'path'            => '/storage/app/uploads',
        'temporaryUrlTTL' => 3600,
    ],

    'media' => [
        'disk'   => 'local',
        'folder' => 'media',
        'path'   => '/storage/app/media',
    ],

],
```

If I now go to the Media tab, it calls the URL
`https://newurl.de/backend/backend/media`.
I can upload an image and it also appears correctly in my file system.
According to Mediamanager it is under `https://newurl.de/storage/app/media/4187.jpg`
which would be correct. However, it gives me a 404 error.

If I call the picture under `http://oldurl.de/octoberCMS/storage/app/media/4187.jpg`, then it works.
I wonder where else the error lies here. In my code I can't find anything with the old URL. The cache is also cleared

EDIT: It seems to that there is something wrong with my .htaccess.
If I delete the the file, I can reach the image (but not the cms anymore) and if I delete the content, there is still the same error

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /
    
    ##
    ## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
    ##
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]

    ##
    ## Black listed folders
    ##
    RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Block all PHP files, except index
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: maybe a problem is that when you specify `root folder` it created a new one from the actual `root`, so in your main site maybe you need to restructure that. just go to `/octoberCMS/storage` copy all things and paste in outer folder  `/storage`... maybe

Comment: I think the structure is correct and also the two URLs are showing to the same folder

Comment: ok, are you directly viewing files from the media manager or from somewhere else, as well if it's okay just share an image of the root dir structure only if it's okay.

Comment: I found out if I delete my htaccess, I can see the image (but the CMS doesnt work anymore). If I just delete the content of the htaccess, there is still the same problem.

Comment: can you please share your `root directory structure screen-shot` .htaccess content needed for entry point so we can not change it or allow root-level folder access to access files